# Bootstrap why my page has a white bar in right side of my page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to make my bootstrap landing page responsive for all displays, so I've started to use media queries to fit the page on iPhone, iPads and other devices, but when I use a phone, there were a white bar on the right of the webpage also the whole template was showed like zoomed out and some h1 tags where on the white bar on the right. I'll show you my code hoping that somebody could help me, I's all day that I was stuck here. I need help. I'm new in front end developing so don't esitate to give me some advice.

```
<template>
   <div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
         <a class="navbar-brand " href="http://exaple.com/">
         <img src="../assets/logo.png" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
         example.com
         </a>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
               <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#sigUP" style="color:white;">Signin</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#mission" style="color:white;">Mission</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="home-page" class="full-height p-4">
         <div class="container pt-500">
            <div class="row pb-6 pt-20">
               <div class="col-lg-6  my-auto ">
                  <div class="text-right text-down mb-3 d-block d-lg-none">
                     <h1 class ="text-color text-right text-down">Hello,</h1>
                     <h1 class="display-1 text-color text-right text-down">Betatester!</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto pt-6">
                  <div class="text-right text-down mb-3 d-none d-lg-block">
                     <h1 class ="text-color text-right text-down">Hello,</h1>
                     <h1 class="display-1 text-color text-right text-down" >Betatester!</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="about" class="bg-light p-3 p-md-5">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <h1 class="display-1 text-color-about text-center"  >example.com is </h1>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left" >
                  the socialnetwork for you
               </h1>
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_p" >Freetime</h1>
               <img src="../assets/exam1.png" height="100">
               <img src="../assets/exam1.png" height="100">
               <img src="../assets/exam1.png" height="100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
               <img src="../assets/about.png" height="300" class="m-4">
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="marketplace" class=" p-4">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
               <img src="../assets/marketplace.png" height="400">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right" >
                  <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right text-color-about_m" >MARKETPLACE</h1>
                  where you can find all you need
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="shops" class=" p-4">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left" >
                  the place where you can contact your
                  <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_s p-4" >FAVORITE </h1>
                  <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_p" >STORE</h1>
               </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
               <img src="../assets/shop.png" height="400">
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="comp" class=" p-4">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
               <img src="../assets/comp.png" height="400">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right" >
                  be
                  <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-right text-color-about_m" >COMPETITIVE</h1>
                  blablablablablablablalbalba
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mission" class=" p-4">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left" style="display: inline-block" >
                  the 
                  <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left text-color-about_s" style="display: inline-block" > MISSION </h1>
               </h1>
               <h3 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-left">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel dolor neque. Vivamus id ultrices nunc. Proin vulputate iaculis tortor ac rhoncus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in lobortis diam, eu ullamcorper ante. Pellentesque sodales felis sit amet metus laoreet sodales. Proin auctor nulla vitae porta pretium. Nullam tempor blandit sem vitae finibus.
               </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
               <img src="../assets/mission.png" height="400">
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="betatest" class=" p-3">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg">
            </div>
            <h1 class="ml-md-0 mr-md-0   text-center display-1">
               Why you'll be 
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center  text-color-about_b display-1">
                  Betatester?
               </h1>
            </h1>
         </div>
         <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg">
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center" style="font-size: 4em;">
                  be
                  <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center" style="display: inline-block; color:white;font-size: 4em;font-size: 1.2em">BETATESTER</h1>
                  helps us to make the best experience possible on example.com
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="sigUP" class=" p-2">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
            <div class="col-lg pd-8">
               <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center display-2">
                  Become
                  <h1 class="ml-md-4 mr-md-4 text-center text-color-about_sn display-4">
                     a BETATESTER
                  </h1>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
            <div class="col-lg ">
               <img src="../assets/player.png">
               <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
                  <div class="col-lg ">
                     <a href="/#/signupPlayer" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom align-self-end" role="button">Player</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg ">
               <img src="../assets/store.png">
               <div class="row justify-content-center pd-8">
                  <div class="col-lg ">
                     <a href="/#/signupStore" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-customS " role="button">Store</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="contact" class="p-5">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
            <div v-if="show_contact == true" class="col-lg-4" style="color:white">
               <h2>Hai una domanda?</h2>
               <p>Contact us!</p>
               <div v-if="contact_notice != ''" class="alert alert-warning">
                  there's a problem. {{contact_notice}}
               </div>
               <form @submit.prevent="sendContactMessage()">
                  <div class="form-group text-left ">
                     <input v-model="contact_email"
                        type="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="............"
                        >
                     <textarea v-model="contact_message"
                        class="form-control mt-3"
                        placeholder="..........."
                        rows="5"
                        ></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send</button>
               </form>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
               <h3>mail sent correctly!</h3>
               <p>thanks for contact us!.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer" class=" p-4">
         <footer class="text-light p-4">
            <small>&copy; 2020,example</small>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
   #home-page {
   background-color: #ff9e0b;
   background: url('../assets/bg_mt.jpg') no-repeat center center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   }
   #about {
   min-height: 40vh;
   }
   #contact {
   background-color: #252223;
   }
   #marketplace {
   background-color: #ff9e0b;
   }
   #comp {
   background-color: #ff9e0b;
   }
   #footer {
   background-color: #252223;
   }
   #betatest {
   background-color: #ff9e0b;
   }
   .navbar-custom { 
   background-color:  #ff9e0b; 
   } 
   /* Modify brand and text color */ 
   .navbar-custom .navbar-brand, 
   .navbar-custom .navbar-text { 
   color: white !important;
   font-size: 1.5em !important; 
   }
   .text-color{
   color:white;
   font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
   font-weight: 600;
   }
   .text-color-about{
   color:#ff9e0b;
   font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
   font-weight: 600;
   }
   .text-color-about_p{
   color:#ff9e0b;
   font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 4em !important;
   }
   .text-color-about_s{
   color:#ff9e0b;
   font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 3em !important;
   }
   .text-color-about_m{
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 3em !important;
   }
   .text-color-about_b{
   color:white;
   font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
   align-self: center;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 2em !important;
   }
   .text-color-about_sn{
   color:#ff9e0b;
   font-family: 'Mountserrat',sans-serif;
   align-self: center;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 1em !important;
   }
   .bg-primary{
   color:#ff9e0b;
   }
   .bg-imgPlayer{
   contain: url(../assets/store-02.png);
   }
   .btn-customS{
   border-radius: 1rem;
   background-color: #f23838 !important;
   }
   .btn-custom{
   border-radius: 1rem;
   background-color: #ff9e0b !important;
   }
   @media (max-width: 576px) { 
   .navbar-custom {
   width:1152px; /* .... */
   }
   .navbar-custom {
   width:1152px; /* .... */
   }
   .about {
   width:1152px; /* .... */
   }
   .home-page {
   width:1152px; /* .... */
   }
   ....
   }
@media (max-width: 375px) { 
.navbar-custom {
         width: 375px;
        
}
.about {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.home-page {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.marketplace {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.shop {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.comp {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.mission {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.betatest {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.sigUP {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.contact {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
.footer {
          width:375px; /* .... */
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: please post the picture also code where you think problem arise?

Comment: I've added the image and indicated with arrows where the bar is.

Comment: one or more elements are overflowing on the right. two options. you can use DevTools to find the faulty elements and fix its width or other behavior (padding, etc.) OR you can silence the problem and set overflow-x to hidden and hope nothing else breaks :) [you can set the overflow-x:hidden only for phones btw ... ]

Comment: Thanks avia, you saved my day :)

Comment: @Loki00 glad I could help! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more elements are overflowing on the right. 2 options

1. you can use DevTools to find the faulty elements and fix its width or other behavior (padding, etc.); OR
2. You can silence the problem and set overflow-x to hidden and hope nothing else breaks [you can set the overflow-x:hidden only for phones]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually setting the font size per each breakpoint, Bootstrap 4.3+ introduced a new feature called [Responsive Font Sizes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/typography/#responsive-font-sizes).

You can follow the instruction to turn it on, then you don't have to write so many media queries. In fact, I would strongly suggest you to learn [SASS/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/), if you're new to it. You can customize Bootstrap so much easier with SASS/SCSS. There is a whole section on [theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/) on the documentation.

Also, you should never need nested containers with Bootstrap:

```html
<!-- <div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0"> -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
        ...
    </nav>
    <div id="home-page" class="full-height p-4">
        <div class="container pt-500">...</div>
    </div>
        ...
    <div id="footer" class=" p-4">
        ...
    </div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

I just feel like there are lots of places you can clean up / improve in your code.